# Batch file to map a drive when the folder name contains spaces

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to map a drive using a batch file.
I have tried:

```
net use m: \\Server01\myfolder /USER:mynetwork\Administrator "Mypassword" /persistent:yes
```

It works fine. The problem comes when I try to map a folder with spaces on its name:

```
net use m: \\Server01\my folder /USER:mynetwork\Administrator "Mypassword" /persistent:yes
```

I have tried using quotes, using myfold~1 but nothing works.

An easy way would be renaming the folder but I have it mapped in more than 300 workstations so is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just created some directories, shared them and mapped using:

```
net use y: "\\mycomputername\folder with spaces"
```

So this solution gets "works on my machine" certificate. What error code do you get?

Comment: Does not work on Windows 7 when used in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

whenever you deal with spaces in filenames, use quotes

```
net use "m:\Server01\my folder" /USER:mynetwork\Administrator "Mypassword" /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Why have you got the drive letter as part of the UNC?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will help you to much by I once needed a batch file to open a game, the .exe was in a folder with blanks (duh!) and I tried : START "C:\Fold 1\fold 2\game.exe" and START C:\Fold 1\fold 2\game.exe - None worked, then I tried

```
   START C:\"Fold 1"\"fold 2"\game.exe and it worked
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
net use "m:\Server01\my folder" /USER:mynetwork\Administrator "Mypassword" /persistent:yes
```

does not work?

Comment: net use "m:\Server01\my folder" /USER:mynetwork\Administrator "Mypassword" /persistent:yes doesn't work

Comment: Why have you got the drive letter as part of the UNC? And why do you still have your April-1 gravatar? :-)

Comment: It was ghostdog74 suggestion. Anyway net use m: "\Server01\my folder" works. Thanks chalup

Comment: @paxdiablo - 'cause I love it! (the gravatar, not the drive letter)

Answer (score 1):

```
net use f: \\\VFServer"\HQ Publications" /persistent:yes
```

Note that the first `quotation mark` goes before the leading `\` and the second goes after the end of the folder name.